# Extracting archive from Krusader doesn't work in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, dolphin, krusader

Extracting archive from context menu in Krusader doesn't work, but works from Dolphin.

Is it a know issue of Krusader in Kubuntu 22.04?

Or can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: I have never done it, but Krusader can have custom actions applied, I would imagine like Unrar etc... though that does not come up in context menu. you'd need to recompile edited source code for that.

Answer (score 1):

`Krusader` `2.8.0` fixes this issue, but in the current LTS `Kubuntu` `Krusader` version is `2.7.2`. So at this point of time user should live with this bug, or build `Krusader` from sources, that is very easy.